# Clear Firefox history on exit except open pages

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, history, browser-tabs

I would like to

1. clear the entire Firefox history on exit, except for
2. currently open windows, tab groups, tabs, pages so that they can be opened the next time Firefox starts,
3. <strike>by the click of a single button.</strike> without clicking anything.

If I set the option "Clear history when Firefox closes" it doesn't do the job. It will erase everything. But that's not what I want.

Is there an Add-On for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not do this already? What happens when you clear the history, close your windows and then start Firefox again? Does the session not restore?

Comment: I didn't explain the problem correctly. I want to make use of Firefoxes "Clear history when Firefox closes" option but I want this option to remove everything except the open tabs. But it will instead erase everything, so Firefox starts with a blank tab.